# Mocking npm package with different returns

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an npm package implementation, both to return a Promise that resolves to true and for another test, I want to reject with an error.

At the top of the test file, before the first test description, I define the following code to mock an npm package:

```js
const mockNewFile = (): File => new File(['this is new file content'], 'new-file');
jest.mock('blueimp-load-image', () => () => {
    const newFile = mockNewFile();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const data = {
            image: {
                toBlob: (func: (file: File) => File) => {
                    func(newFile);
                }
            }
        };

        resolve(data);
    });
});
```

With this, I'm able to run my tests successfully for a function that relies on this npm package, called `blueimp-load-image`

But then I wanted to add a test for what should happen if this `blueimp-load-image` function fails, that is, when the promise it returns is rejected.

To do this I created a new description block within the main description block of the test file and tried to mock the npm package again there, by having it return a different:

```js
describe('if loadImage returns an error', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                jest.mock('blueimp-load-image', () => () => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) = reject(new Error('something went wrong')));
                });
            });

            test('return the file back unmodified', async () => {
                const expected = {/* file content */};
                const result = await theFunctionUsingLoadImage(file);

                expect(result).toStrictEqual(expected);
            });
        });
```

The test above here fails because no error seems to be thrown, leading me to expect that the mock created in the `beforeEach` block is not working. I know this because the `expected` and `result` should be the same, it would only differ if there was no error.

I've tried to figure this out as well using jest.spyOn instado of Jest.mock but that attempt was a complete failure.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jest.mock` can be called only once, and should implement the entire interface of the mocked lib.

There are several possible options:

1. Using [**mocks**](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), which allows you to write a mock implementation which can expose additional (mock only) methods.
2. Using `jest.mock` with global variable which will control if the mock should return success or reject.

This is an example of the second option

```
const mockNewFile = (): File => new File(['this is new file content'], 'new-file');
let shouldSuccess = true;
jest.mock('blueimp-load-image', () => () => {
    const newFile = mockNewFile();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!shouldSuccess) {
          return reject('data-of-reject');
        }
        const data = {
            image: {
                toBlob: (func: (file: File) => File) => {
                    func(newFile);
                }
            }
        };

        resolve(data);
    });
});
```

Now all you need to do is to change the value of `shouldSuccess` to false, in order to make your mock implementation to reject.

Comment: This works, maybe not the ideal way to do mock it but the best solution I've seen so far to fix the problem with the way I've done it :)

Comment: Just one note, jest.mock does not allow any out of scope variables, except for some exceptions. However, if the `shouldSuccess` is prefixed with `mock` then it can be used.